# How to convert string to datetime in javascript in a specific format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

So, I don't dabble in Javascript much, but I'm attempting to format a string from something like '2021-05-24 05:23 PM' to something like 2021-05-24 17:23. Is theres a library I could use or a built in method I haven't user properly yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function. It will receive a datetime string of 12 hours format as parameter and return the 24 hours format time.

```
    function formatTo24(date) {
        let only_date = date.split(" ")[0];
        let time = date.split(" ")[1];
        let ampm = date.split(" ")[2];

        if (ampm == "PM") {
            let hours = time.split(":")[0];
            let minutes = time.split(":")[1];
            let hours24 = JSON.parse(Number(hours)) + 12;
            return only_date + " " + hours24 + ":" + minutes;
        } else {
            return only_date + " " + time;
        }
    }

    console.log( formatTo24('2021-05-24 05:23 PM') ); 
    //Output: 2021-05-24 17:23
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't particularly helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. You should also consider using features to reduce the code, e.g. instead of using *split* 5 times, use `let [d, h, m, ampm = date.split(/[\s:]/)`  and `JSON.parse(Number(hours)) + 12` could be `+hours + 12`.